# IOS Back to main page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

i am a ios newbie dev.

I used android developers seem difficult to understand for IOS.

I have a question.

use the this code to start a new page from main page.

```
addMember_1 = [[AddMember_1 alloc] init];
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addMember_1];
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

i want to back main page, how can i do

i try to Build the button for back to main

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemReply target:self action:@selector(selectLeftAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
-(void)selectLeftAction:(id)sender
{
    /* I used this more but not work!
     addsubview
     removeFromSuperview */
    [UIView bringSubviewToFront: Subview];
}
```

Comment: if you have navigation controller, you should learn to use the `–popViewControllerAnimated:`, `–popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` or `–dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` methods instead (depends on how you put your view into the navigation stack). if you have not added any sub-view explicitly, it is not your concern to call the `–removeFromSuperview` method.

Comment: Your question is not clear, decide first exact flow for views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting to work with iOS do some search to know handling views. `ViewController (iOS) == (Android) Activity`

> In **Android** you could've use `startActivity(intent);` and `finish();` to handle your activities.

1. `startActivity == pushViewController`
2. `finish == popViewController`

---

## [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html)

The `UINavigationController` class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This navigation interface makes it possible to present your data efficiently and makes it easier for the user to navigate that content.

So, for example with your case. You can start your view with `UINavigationController` hierarchy like below,

```
addMember_1 = [[AddMember_1 alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addMember animated:YES];
```

And, redirecting to your preview you can use this,

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you add more than one ViewControllers and you want to redirect to your root ViewController, just use below code,

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this clarify your doubts.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

To present your view use navigation controller like

```
addMember_1 = [[AddMember_1 alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:addMember animated:YES];
```

And add this in your target method, to pop off the view controller from te navigation stack.

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want move to main (root) page (not previous):

```
- (void)goBack{
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this like of code on your `UIButton` action of back button.

```
- (IBAction)btnBackAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```